# Laravel 7 model factory is throwing "InvalidArgumentException: Unknown formatter" exception for faker

Tags: laravel, faker, laravel-8, laravel-factory

I started building a web application using Laravel 8. I have noticed that a couple of things have changed in the Laravel 8 including model factory. Now, I am writing a unit test using factories for models. But it is throwing error when I fake the fields using faker.

This is my test method.

```
public function testHasRoleReturnsTrue()
{
    $user = User::factory()->create();
}
```

As you can see, all I am trying to do right now is that I am trying to create a user using factory. This is my factory class for user model.

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = User::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
}
```

As you can see I am faking values using faker. When I run the test, I got the following error.

```
InvalidArgumentException: Unknown formatter "name"

/var/www/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php:248
/var/www/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php:228
/var/www/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php:274
/var/www/database/factories/UserFactory.php:28
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:366
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:345
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:329
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php:157
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:334
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:302
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php:228
```

I assume that the error is because I am using faker. But I cannot spot any issue in the code. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: is this a unit test??

Comment: Yes. It is unit test.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because you are using this in Unit tests. And it is extending PhpUnit's TestCase.

When you extend Laravel's TestCase it should work.

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue. Cheers.

Comment: If anyone is using PHPStorm you can also update the "PHPUnit 6 Test" template from `Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates`.  Just need to correct the `TestCase` import to use `Tests\TestCase`.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/testing they actually use `use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;` to extend their tests class...

Comment: But that's why you cannot use Faker inside Unit tests, maybe it's on purpose.

Comment: Well, currently I am extending TestCase which boots up Laravel application and it is still complaining about unknown formatters.
Composer dependencies are updated, in tinker factories work like expected. I am actually without any clues at this point.